# Load jnlp file using relative path

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have an applet ,whose init() method calls an jnlp file which downloads a jar.(using Runtime class and exec('javaws +path of jnlp).
But am not able to give a realtive path of jnlp file.
Is there any workaround from which i can supply realtive path?Works when i give an absolute path of jnlp file.

Comment: please give us some examples of a) what is working and b) what you tried so far

Comment: jawaws +absolute path(C:\\..myfile.jnlp) works fine.but relative path wont work with jnlp.Right now im using class laoder to get the path of jnlp.Is there any way i can incorporate relative path

Comment: what relative paths did you try? And relative to what? "myfile.jnlp" or "/myfile.jnlp" or codebase/myfile.jnlp ... there are lots of possibilities. Did you even set the codebase? And where is this jnlp file located? Inside the applet.jar? Next to it?

Comment: I have a web project which calls an applet class.this applet in turn calls an jnlp file which downloads a jar.I tried all possible relative paths.i have the jnlp file in lib of my web project.the path (webproject/webcontent/lib).just want to call this path relatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An applet runs inside a web browser and your jnlp file is still on the web server. So you can't access it via file system - even if you have the permission, because it is simply not there. Two possibilities:

1.)
Access your jnlp file via `http://yourwebserver.domain/webproject/webcontent/lib/myfile.jnlp`

2.)
Add your jnlp file to your applet.jar and load it with: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myfile.jnlp");`

Answer (score 1):

> ..jnlp file in lib of my web project

It will not be accessible there, and should be moved to an area on the server that is available to a browser (and the JWS Client that is trying to access it).

Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).  When loading the JNLP, use the address the end user would use to get it (and not an address on the file system).